# Centos CakePHP 3 not connect to oracle database

Tags: oracle, cakephp, centos, oracle-call-interface

to connect to oracle database from my project cakephp, Im using CakeDC, it's working perfectly on windows, but not with centos

Database driver CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\Driver\OracleOCI cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

php -i |grep oci

[image]

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend you paste the body of your code I the post so that others can reference it quickly. Unfortunately, people aren't nearly as likely to be able to help if it's on a separate page.

Comment: Install the OCI8 extension.  Install an Oracle Client, e.g. Oracle Instant Client and configure the library search path with ldconfig.  See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html for downloads and installation instructions.